# using angular js template inside django {% static %} tag

Tags: angularjs, django

I am trying to load the image on the basis of name from the database.

I am fetching the database value from `angular` `ajax` request. Now the problem is how to use the `angular` template in static tag of `django`.

```
<div ng-repeat="result in dbresults">
   <img src= {% static '/images/'{[{result.db}]}'.png' %}>
</div>
```

Comment: You can not do that, since Django templates are rendered by the server, Angular by the client. You will need to use the "root" of static, and then fill in the Angular variable unevaluated.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you plz give me a example

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i got, what you ment, Thanks, its solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using root path instead of using static tag solved the issue.